# How to run classify_image on multiple GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I want to run vectorization on images using multiple GPUs (for now my script use only one GPU). I have a list of images, graph and session. THe script's output is saved vector. My machine has 3 NVIDIA GPU. Environment: Ubuntu, python 3.7, Tensorflow 2.0 (with GPU support).
Here is my code example (initialization session):

```
def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
     # We load the protobuf file from the disk and parse it to retrieve the
     # unserialized graph_def
     with tf.io.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
         graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
         graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
     # Then, we import the graph_def into a new Graph and returns it
     with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
         # The name var will prefix every op/nodes in your graph
         # Since we load everything in a new graph, this is not needed
         tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
     return graph

GRAPH = load_graph(os.path.join(settings.IMAGENET_PATH['PATH'], 'classify_image_graph_def.pb'))
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.9
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
SESSION = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=GRAPH, config=config)
```

After that I called run vectorization as:

```
sess = SESSION
for image_index, image in enumerate(image_list):
    with Image.open(image) as f:
        image_data = f.convert('RGB')
        feature_tensor = POOL_TENSOR
        feature_set = sess.run(feature_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg:0': image_data})
        feature_vector = np.squeeze(feature_set)
        outfile_name = os.path.basename(image) + ".vc"
        this_is_path = settings.VECTORS_DIR_PATH['PATH']
        out_path = os.path.join(this_is_path, outfile_name)
        np.savetxt(out_path, feature_vector, delimiter=',')
```

This worked example runs on first GPU 100 vectors in 29 seconds.
So, I tried [this distributed training method](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#mirroredstrategy) from Tensorflow docs to run on multiple GPUs:

```
mirorred_strategy = tf.distribute.MirorredStrategy()
with mirorred_strategy.scope():
    sess = SESSION
    # and here all the code from previous example after session:
    for image_index, image in enumerate(image_list):
        with Image.open(image) as f:
            image_data = f.convert('RGB')
            feature_tensor = POOL_TENSOR
            feature_set = sess.run(feature_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg:0': image_data})
            feature_vector = np.squeeze(feature_set)
            outfile_name = os.path.basename(image) + ".vc"
            this_is_path = settings.VECTORS_DIR_PATH['PATH']
            out_path = os.path.join(this_is_path, outfile_name)
            np.savetxt(out_path, feature_vector, delimiter=',')
```

After I checked the logs, I can conclude that Tensorflow has access to all three GPU. However, this does not change anything: when running, Tensorflow is stil using only the first GPU (100 vectors in 29 seconds).
Another method I tried is I manually set each item to concrete GPU instance:

```
sess = SESSION
for image_index, image in enumerate(image_list):
    if image_index % 2 == 0:
        device_name = '/gpu:1'
    elif image_index % 3 == 0:
        device_name = '/gpu:2'
    else:
        device_name = '/gpu:0'
    with tf.device(device_name):
        with Image.open(image) as f:
            image_data = f.convert('RGB')
            feature_tensor = POOL_TENSOR
            feature_set = sess.run(feature_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg:0': image_data})
            feature_vector = np.squeeze(feature_set)
            outfile_name = os.path.basename(image) + ".vc"
            this_is_path = settings.VECTORS_DIR_PATH['PATH']
            out_path = os.path.join(this_is_path, outfile_name)
            np.savetxt(out_path, feature_vector, delimiter=',')
```

Monitoring this method I observe every GPU being used but no performance speedup is seen because Tensorflow is swapping from one GPU device to another. So, on first item `GPU:0` will be used and `GPU:1`, `GPU:2`are just waiting, on second item `GPU:1` will be working and `GPU:0`, `GPU:2` will be waiting.
I am also tried another Tensorflow strategy from tf [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training) - without any changes. Also tried to define `tf.Session()` inside the for loop - without success. And [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41605226/9461974) - but cannot make it work for my code.

My questions are:

1) If there a way to modify `tf.distribute.MirorredStrategy()` to make Tensorflow use all three GPU?

2) If answer on (1) is not, how can I run vectorization using all GPU power(maybe here exists async way for doing this or something)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your `mirorred_strategy` (from the third code snippet) is not using all GPUs is that your model input is manually given (using the TF1-style `feature_tensor` tensor) and TensorFlow doesn't know how to automatically distribute data evenly to your GPUs, you may take a look at the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu).

And the fourth snippet (last one) also fails because the way you use it is not correct, you can try to first construct your model graph and then run the graph in a session, but not put them together, you can try to move the `feature_set = sess.run(feature_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg:0': image_data})` outside the for loop. The guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#manual_placement) may illustrate a bit better.

Comment: I cannot move `sess.run(feature_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg:0': image_data})` outside the for loop. For each iteration in `for` loop I open a new image and get `image_data` from it. After that I run `sess.run()` on this `image_data`. So, I can not move `image_data` from `for` loop

Comment: You can build a generator from your image data and append to a list, similarly build your TF graph and use a list to hold the graph handles in the for loop, just don't run the `sess` in the `for` loop. You can use another for loop to actually fetch the images and run the session.

Comment: can you provide an example in code(even simple)? Because I do not understand how to do what you are described here. How to build graph for each image(load default graph or so?)

Comment: @Oysiyl, I'll explain a bit more using the examples from the official guide I said in the answer, see https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/G6av3MjH